# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components ) or a class /function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello i'm getting this error when tried to implement a header containing a logout button. The error i'm getting is to check the render method.But can't figure out the error.The file in which i'm getting error is the following

```
  import React from "react";
    import {
      ScrollView,
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      Text,
      Button,
      Title,
      Header,
      AsyncStorage,
      Icon
    } from "react-native";
    import {
      RkText,
    } from "react-native-ui-kitten";
    import Card from "./Card";
    import CardSection from "./CardSection";
    import Login from './Login';


    export class GridV2 extends React.Component {
      onPressLogout(){
          AsyncStorage.removeItem(token);
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <View>
        <Header style={{backgroundColor:'#B00000'}}>    
               <Button
                  transparent
                  onPress={() => this.onPressLogout()}
                >
                  <Icon 
                  style= {{color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 25, paddingTop:0}}
                  name="bars" />
                </Button>
            </Header>
          <Card>
              <CardSection>
            </CardSection>
          </Card>

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

I'm importing this GridV2 in my Login screen.Login screen is as follows. What is the mistake in this code?Please help..

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import  { Container,
        Title,
        InputGroup,
        Input,
        Button,
        Text,
        View,
        Spinner,
        Item,
        Label,  
    }  from 'native-base';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        Image,
        Navigator,
        TouchableOpacity,
        AsyncStorage,
        Linking
    } from 'react-native';

    import QASection from './QASection';
    import GridV2 from './grid2';

    class Login extends Component{
        state = { userdetail: [] };
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.initialState = {
                isLoading: false,
                error: null,
                username: '',
                password: ''        
            };
            this.state = this.initialState;
        }
        render() {
            return();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got your exports/imports wrong. Please remove all unused imports and check if the ones you are importing are in the package they are imported from. For example, as far as I know, there is no such thing as `Header` component in react-native ([DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html)
You should import `GridV2` using named import:

```
import { GridV2 } from './grid2';
```

or export is as a default first:

```
export default class GridV2 extends React.Component {
```

Please check if your other imports are intact (you have correct filenames etc.).
This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) explains exports/imports well.

Also you should not return like this `return ();` from render method. Instead return null like below:

```
return (null);
```

Comment: I got this error when i tried to add a header component and add a button within that header.If i removed that code then it will work perfectly.Why i'm adding a button over there is to perform logout functionality.Please provide any solution